# Send Email when user is subscribed

Tags: node.js, angular, mean, nodemailer

I wrote in my back end this method
    router.put('/validateAccount', function (req, res) {//here is the code that implements nodemailer}

I wanted to call it in my angular Front-end So I wrote a function in the inscription.service.ts

```
ValidateAccount(user){
// var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
// let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3333/api/validateAccount',user)   .map((response: Response) => response.json(),err =>err)
```

}

and I want to use it in inscription.component.ts inside the same function that calls the AddUser() method from the same service

```
register(event) {
event.preventDefault();
let newUser = {
  type:"particulier",
  login:this.login,
  email: this.email,
  tele: this.tele,
  pass: this.pass,
  confpass: this.confpass
}
this.inscriptionService.AddUser(newUser).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
  this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
  this._router.navigate(['/inscription']);

},err=>{
  // console.log(err)
  // this.message = "email existe déjà"
  // this.showMessage = true;
  alert("email existe deja");
})
```

}

Would that be possible, otherwise what shoud I do

Comment: So you want to call validate before addUser?

Comment: Yes!  exactly. So I can send a verifcation email to the subscriber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to do it using RxJS(like using flatMap instead of subscribing to the first http call) but that should to it:

```
this.inscriptionService.AddUser(newUser).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
      this._router.navigate(['/inscription']);
      this.inscriptionService.ValidateAccount(res).map(res => {
        // do something
      }
    }
```